# How to reset a form using: input type=reset

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, reset

Hi this is my first Question here so forgive me if I get it wrong.

I am trying to reset a form using The input type=reset tag in HTML5 but am having problems. I will put in a part of my code, and the question I am asking is:
Does it matter if the forms are in a seprate div? I will be putting in Javascript so if you could tell me a simple JS method that would be great, but not jQuery.Any help you could offer would be great!

This is all in a feildset.

```
<div id="formset">
  <label for="textfield" class="form">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" class="input">




 <p></p>
  <label for="textfield2">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" class="input">



<p></p>
  <label for="email"></label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input">
  <p></p>
    <label for="date"></label>


<input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="input"></div> <input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: needs a `<form>` tag for reset to work, divs inside make no diff.

Comment: Thank you @dandavis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I think you need to use form tag. Here is my code:

<form action="" method="">
        <div id="formset">
            <label for="textfield" class="form">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" class="input">

            <p></p>
            <label for="textfield2">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" class="input">

            <p></p>
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input">
            <p></p>
            <label for="date"></label>

            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="input">
        </div> 

        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't belive i messed that up. Thank you Again you have realy helped.

Answer (score 0):

Without form tag A form cannot declare as a form. you can use all of form event such as submit,reset etc. when you use a form tag. like this

```
<form action="" method="">
  your inputs.....
</form>
```